# Flutter View does not update view while Provider call notifyListeners()

Tags: flutter, stream, future, flutter-provider, flutter-listview

I want to the View update list item when provider function called. But it does not work.
Before changing normal View to `FutureBuilder`, it worked. I tried to use `StreamBuilder` instead, does not work either.

How can I solve this?

Here is the Provider:

```dart
class SelectArtistProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Map> artists = [];
  ...
  Future initArtistListVM() async { //for Future Builder
    var allArtists =
        await Firestore.instance.collection('artists').getDocuments();

    List list = allArtists.documents
        .map((artist) => {
              'id': artist.documentID,
              'name': artist.data['name'],
              'image': "artist.data['image'],
              'selected': "false",
            })
        .toList();
    artists = list;
    notifyListeners();
    return artists;
  }

  void toggleSelected(Map item, int index) {
    artists[index]['selected'] = !item['selected'];
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

View

```
// list view
class SelectArtist extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final selectArtistProvider = Provider.of<SelectArtistProvider>(context);
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: selectArtistProvider.initArtistListVM(), // initial data from api
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return ListView.builder(
          ...
          child: ArtistItem(index, selectArtistProvider.artists[index])


// item view
class ArtistItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  final Map artist;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final selectArtistProvider = Provider.of<SelectArtistProvider>(context);
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => selectArtistProvider.toggleSelected(artist, index),
        child: 
          ...
          Visibility(
            visible: artist['selected'],
            child: SomeWidget()
            ...

// root view to place providers
class InitialProviders extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ...
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SelectArtistProvider()),
        ],
        child: ...
```

Comment: I noticed `FutureBuilder` is called whenever ArtistItem call `toggleSelected()` so that `artists` is overwritten every time `toggleSelected()` update `artists`. What can I do for it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved This!

Change `initArtistListVM()` some part.

```
if (artists.isEmpty) {
    artists = list;
    notifyListeners();
}
```